# working with JS Classical with instance methods

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to analyze the flow of classical model and test different methods if it's going to work. First, I have instantiated `ans1` then I've tried to assign the function `ans1.area` to `ans2` believing that it would pass the reference  but when I tried to call `area()` in `ans2` it didn't work - `ans2.area()`, Isn't it should be passing the reference of the function? Whereas 
when I assigned `ans1` to `ans2` and tried to call `ans2.area()` it has the same value with `ans1`. Can you please help and elaborate it. Thank you.

```
  function Rectangle(length,width){

     this.length = length;
     this.width = width;

    }

    Rectangle.prototype.perimeter= function(){

       var perimeterAns = this.length + this.length + this.width + this.width;
       return perimeterAns;

      };

    Rectangle.prototype.area= function(){

          var areaAns = (2*this.length + 2*this.width);
          return areaAns;

      };


    var ans1 = new Rectangle(5,6);
    ans1.area(); // 22

    // not working
    var ans2 = ans1.area
    ans2(); // Nan

    ans2 = ans1;
    ans2.area(); // 22;
```

Comment: var ans2 = ans1.area is missing brackets. Should be ans1.area()

Comment: What about var ans2 = ans1.area? Why is it when I did this - var ans2 = ans1.area
ans2(); // Nan -  it returned NaN. Can you please explain it further

Comment: also isn't area more `this.length*this.width`

Comment: The answers below are good...FYI, you can also explicitly specify the `this` variable with `call()` or `apply()`, e.g. `var areaMethod = ans1.area; areaMethod.call(ans1);`

Comment: haha disregard the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'e because the `ans2` variable is merely referencing the `area` function but is lacking its original *context* (which is the object referenced by the `ans1` variable). So the `this` in the function would actually be `window` (the global context) and you end up with `NaN` due to invalid values.

You can use `bind` to bind the function to the original context:

```
var ans2 = ans1.area.bind(ans1);
```

Or

```
var ans2 = Rectangle.prototype.area.bind(ans1);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

When you do var **ans2 = ans1.area;**, you have assigned a function to ans2. So when you call **ans2.area()**, **this** doesn't refer to a **Rect** object, it refers to global object, which doesn't have **length** and **width** properties.

See [Custom Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Custom_objects) for a brief explaination of how this works in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in the `function area` please the way the `length` and `width` variables are accessed (using `this`) - what this means is access `length and width` variables from the object where you want the operation to be executed.

Now to your first question, see my answer inline

`// not working
    var ans2 = ans1.area  // Copy the function area to a variable
    ans2(); // Nan  // here when you call the function, this object points to   //global object where length and width is undefined`

second question, find my answer inline

`ans2 = ans1;
    ans2.area(); // 22;object assigns by reference, so when you call the function on second copy object then it like calling on the same object, thats why the same answer`

`